# UIImagePickerController in Qt 5.3

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, qt5.3

I want to implement an application for `iOS`. I’ve used `Qt 5.3` on `Mac`. I want to defined user interface in `Qt`. I want to have a button on `*.ui`. When clicking on that, `iOS` photo library will be opened and then user can be able to select a photo. I know that I must use `UIImagePickerController`.

I have to use the root controller and show the UIPickerImageController on that.
For doing so, I need to use some internal `Qt API`:

first, in the `*.pro`:

```
QT += gui-private
```

then, in my `*.mm` code get the pointer to the root view controller of the `Qt` app:

```
UIView *view = static_cast<UIView *>( QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface()->nativeResourceForWindow("uiview",quickView) );
UIViewController* rootCtrl = [[view window] rootViewController];
```

and now, I can show the `UIImagePickeController`:

```
[rootCtrl presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completation:nil]
```

this way to get the root view controller with `QML`, solved my problem but I don’t want to use `QML`. Is there another way to get a pointer to the main root view controller of the `Qt` application(`C++` + `Objective-C`) without using `QML`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use UIApplication and keyWindow property:

```
UIViewController* rootViewController = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow rootViewController];
```